# Why did my onclick attribute in input type button is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom, onclick

Here is My code

```
    <form name="formA">
      <input type="text" name="iptA" id="iptA" value="" />
      <input type="button" name="btnA" id="btnA" value="Click Here" onclick="count();"/>
      <input type="button" name="btnClr" id="btnClr" value="Clear" onclick="clear();"/>
      
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      var a = 0;
      document.formA.iptA.value = a;
      function count(){
        a++;
        document.formA.iptA.value = a;
      }
      
      function clear(){
        a = 0;
        document.formA.iptA.value = a;
      }
    </script>
```

In this, the function `count()` is working properly but the second function `clear()` is not working.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename `clear` to `foo` and it will work. `clear` already has a meaning in browser pov  - clearing the `console`

Comment: Upvoted. Here's the link to the respective MDN page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/clear

Comment: Yeah , I just changed clear() to clearA() it worked!